# Intermittent bug post closed for wrong reason

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, incorrectly-closed

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/q/498268/258567) was closed as not reproducible, but actually confirms [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1320020) perfectly. Should it be re-opened and closed for the right reason (as a bug)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure it's a problem represented by that bug, [**answer it**](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/8822/449). I've reopened it to allow that.

I consider this a much healthier option to just shutting the question down. I've been through [the reasoning](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7841/please-try-to-read-bug-reports-before-voting-to-close-something-as-a-bug) before but if nothing else, it gives us a duplicate target for future questions about the same problem.

I note that in this case we're talking about a bug you reported which is still currently un-triaged and hasn't progressed at all, and (as far as I can tell from the report) hasn't been pushed upstream. There are going to be some issues. I don't think that neccessarily rules it out from being a viable answer but point out its status and what it needs to be improved (perhaps other people can help).

Comment: I've turned it and Windows 8 questions into a canned comment (with Autocomment).

Answer (score 2):

> This question was closed as not reproducible

[Comment on the question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498268/ubuntu-14-04-no-sound-from-speaker#comment669908_498268):

> A couple of reboots later and **it has decided to start working again.** I have no idea what happened here but its working again.

It was closed with the correct close reason, it doesn't need to be reopened.